# VBA code doesn't run when cursor remains at updated Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show a message 20 seconds after opening the Excel workbook. Code is:

```
//ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetTimer
End Sub

//Module1
Public Sub SetTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "ShowMsg"
End Sub

Public Sub ShowMsg()
    MsgBox ("my message")
End Sub
```

As you see, code is very simple and it works when user don't update sheet or when they leave updated/focused cell. However, if cursor remains at cell the message will never be shown. It seams that control doesn't return to VBA code while a cell has focus or is updating. Any idea for this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

```
Sub main()

    Dim start As Single

    start = Timer

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Timer > (start + 20) '20 seconds
    MsgBox "hello"

End Sub
```

**Edit. Code for further question:**

In a module called Module1, enter the following code:

```
Public start As Single

Sub main2()

    start = Timer

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Timer > (start + 20) '20 seconds
    MsgBox "hello"

End Sub
```

In your ThisWorkbook object (double click on ThisWorkbook from the list of objects in the Project Explorer) enter the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Module1.start = Module1.start + 5
End Sub
```

Every time any cell in any worksheet in the workbook is changed, another five seconds is added to the timer.

Comment: You won't be able to run any other VBA code while this is running I don't think.

Comment: Nice - I had always thought that VBA was blocked once a user was in edit mode - clearly not the case...  And other VBA code will run "in parallel" with the timer loop - tested both a simple messagebox and a worksheet event.

Comment: This was a bit of a fluke, actually. I was messing around making callbacks from EnumWindows (yeah I know, little bit dodgy), thinking maybe Windows would hijack my function and run it within its own process (maybe this highlights my ignorance about such things). Anyway, it seemed to work in a callback so I tried it outside of one and it was fine. Brilliant :). @Tim Williams I'm surprised the event interrupted the running code, interesting!

Comment: Can we postpone the hello message each time user updates a cell. I tried to do that by updating start time after each cell change. But it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: @Bob I've updated my answer. Can I ask, are you making some sort of hilarious "keep working" reminder?

Comment: No, I just wanted to simplify the problem by this example.

Comment: Haha, I'm a little disappointed. Quite disappointed, actually. Let me know if the updated code doesn't work for you.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I did the same before you post, any why disappointed!

Comment: Does it give you any errors? I noticed that if I had more than one workbook open when I was testing the code, I couldn't get to the relevant workbook to enter data. Not sure if this will cause you any problems.

Comment: Do you call main2 from Workbook_Open()? I noticed that I have to wait 20 second each time I open the sheet. this behaviour is not related to code for updating start.

Comment: Wait twenty seconds for what, exactly? You mean before you can interact with the workbook?